# Function returning before awaited Task has completed

Tags: c#, async-await, amazon-dynamodb

The order of async-await operations in this bit of code is a bit off. The `await` Task inside `DownloadMetasBySortAsync` isn't behaving like I thought it should. The task completes itself, but only after `DownloadMetasBySortAsync` has already returned `null` to `DownloadMetasAsync`.

I've tried adding `Task.Wait()` on the tasks in `DownloadMetasAsync` *and* the offending, awaited task. I tried `ConfigureAwait()`. `DownloadMetasBySortAsync` always kicks back `null` before the needed task has been finished.

What am I missing?

```cs
public async Task<List<MyMeta>> DownloadMetasAsync(SortType sortType)
{
    ResetFlags();
    _cloudMetas = await DownloadMetasBySortAsync(sortType);
    Debug.Log((_cloudMetas != null) ? _cloudMetas.Count + " metas downloaded" : "NULL cloudmetas");
    return _cloudMetas;
}

private async Task<List<MyMeta>> DownloadMetasBySortAsync(SortType sortType)
{
    //Load Table
    Table dbTable = null;
    //Can't call LoadTable from main thread
    await Task.Run(() => { 
        try {
            dbTable = Table.LoadTable(DBClient, new TableConfig(_databaseName));
        }catch( Exception ex ) {
            _operationFailed = true;
            ThrowError(ex);
        }
    });
    if(dbTable == null ) { return null; }

    //Set up secondary local index if needed
    string sortIndex = (sortType == SortType.Creator) ? "date-creator-index" : null;

    return await ScanTable(_dbName, sortIndex); //Scan table for list of metas
}

private async Task<List<MyMeta>> ScanTable(string dbName, string index)
{
    List<MyMeta> metaList = null;
    try {
        Dictionary<string,AttributeValue> lastKeyEvaluated = null;

        do {
            var request = new ScanRequest
            {
                TableName = dbName,
                IndexName = index,
                ConsistentRead = true,
                ExclusiveStartKey = lastKeyEvaluated
            };
            Debug.Log("Scanning...");
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                DBClient.ScanAsync(request, (responseObj) =>
                {
                    if( responseObj == null ) {
                        Debug.LogWarning("Response NULL");
                    }
                    else {
                        Debug.Log("Response received");
                        if(metaList == null ) { metaList = new List<MyMeta>(); }
                        var resultList = ProcessScanResult(responseObj.Response);
                        if( resultList != null && resultList.Count > 0 ) {
                            metaList.AddRange(resultList);
                        }
                    }
                    lastKeyEvaluated = responseObj.Response.LastEvaluatedKey;
                });
            });

        } while( lastKeyEvaluated != null && lastKeyEvaluated.Count != 0 );
    }
    catch( Exception ex ) {
        ThrowError(ex);
    }

    return metaList;
}
```

Comment: The DBClient.ScanAsync looks like a method that calls a callback so I assume it returns immediately and that’s why this happens. If there isn’t an actual async version you can make your own TaskCompletionSource etc and use that to await the completion.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. ScanAsync isn't awaitable, so I thought wrapping it with Task.Run would solve that. I can see why it could return immediately.
Now I've implemented TaskCompletionSource using the [RunAsync function found on MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/06/02/the-nature-of-taskcompletionsourcetresult/)  But calling it with 'await RunAsync(() => DBClient.ScanAsync...` isn't affecting the outcome.  Should I be calling that a different way?

Comment: You’ll create the completion source, await it and inside the async (which doesn’t need to be in Task.Run even) set it. I’ll check if I have a nice piece of code to give you, I’m on mobile right now so will take a minute to switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `DBClient.ScanAsync` is not an async/await method but a callback type of async method it will return immediately after being called and the results will only come later. To handle this you can use `TaskCompletionSource` to make it into awaitable thing:

```
var task = new TaskCompletionSource<responseObjType>();

DBClient.ScanAsync(request, (responseObj) =>
{
    task.SetResult(responseObj);
}

// Will wait for the callback to be called before continuing and get the results
var responseObj = await task.Task;

if( responseObj == null )
{
    ...
```

This way the method will wait until the callback is called, the data is sent back via the `TaskCompletionSource` object and your code can process it further. This assumes you don't specifically want to run the rest of the code inside the callback, for threading purposes or anything, and will return to the main code flow to do the rest. You can also do the processing in the callback if you want.

Comment: Okay, now I see what's going on. Thank you so much, this was driving me crazy!